# Receiving a message back on user computer running the agent which is also sending the message

Tags: message-queue, publish-subscribe, messaging

I have an agent running on user's local computer, he makes changes to a file locally, or some other process update a file locally. Agent sends message to a messaging queue, messaging queue updates the dashboard or to whatever subscribing the queue, the user sees the update on the dashboard and clicks on commit/Accepts the file changes.

Can queue send the message back to the user's computer so that agent receives it back and perform the commit action.

[image]

The file shown as on local computer can file a file on a remote server a workstation.